# Porque devemos usar anonymous functions com jQuery ao invés da função diretamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma dúvida, alguns métodos do jQuery esperam uma função como parâmetro, mas para funcionar devem receber uma inner function como parâmetro ao invés de uma função diretamente, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$("a").on("click", function() { retornaNada(); });
```

ao invés de

```
$("a").on("click", retornaNada());
```

Considerem `retornaNada()` como uma função qualquer tipo sem corpo de código. Por que não podemos passar a função diretamente?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Os métodos que esperam uma função esperam uma *referência* à função. Por exemplo:

```
$("a").on("click", retornaNada);
```

Isso é vantajoso se você quiser usar a mesma função como event handler em mais de um lugar. Por exemplo:

```
$("a").on("click", retornaNada); 
$("span").on("click", retornaNada);
```

Passando funções anônimas, seria necessário criar duas funções diferentes.

Agora, repare que o que você fez foi:

```
$("a").on("click", retornaNada()); 
//                  ----------^^
```

Você *chamou* a função, e na verdade passou como handler o valor de retorno dela. Como `retornaNada` não retorna nada, incluir os parênteses significa o mesmo que:

```
$("a").on("click", undefined);
```

Por isso não funciona.

Comment: Entendi agora o problema, na verdade o parâmetro esperado não é uma função e sim uma referência para uma função. Mesmo que `retornaNada()` fosse `retornaUm() { return 1; }` o problema seria o mesmo, certo?

Comment: Exatamente! Agora, se fosse `function retornaFunc() { return function(){ console.log(this) };}` funcionaria, e o elemento clicado seria logado no console. Porque aí sim você estaria retornando uma função.

Comment: sim @PhilippeGioseffi o problema seria o mesmo, pois o javascript pode armazenar funções em variáveis que seriam closures, onde você estaria passando o comando para executa-la ao inves de passar a referência dela em si. Estude closures[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures] que você irá entender tudo que precisa saber referente a isto. :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto, obrigado pelo link, lerei com atenção.

Comment: @bfavaretto entendi seu exemplo, agora em questão de performance é melhor utilizar com referência à função ou anonymous function? E outra como passar argumentos para a função em ambos os casos?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Não tem diferença prática em termos de performance. Só que se você coloca o mesmo evento em múltiplos elementos (com várias chamadas a `.on`) você economiza memória se passar sempre uma referência à mesma função. Sobre passar argumentos, merece uma pergunta à parte, a resposta não vai caber num comentário :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Obrigado pela resposta sobre performance. Criarei a segunda pergunta então.

Comment: @bfavaretto Segue a pergunta: [Como passar parâmetros em chamadas de funções por referência em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3924/como-passar-parametros-em-chamadas-de-funcoes-por-referencia-em-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode mandar somente o nome da função. por exemplo:
Você declara a function que vai tratar o evento antes:

```
function meuOnClick() {
...
}
```

E aí faz o seu jquery apontar pra ela:

```
$("a").on("click", meuOnClick);
```

Note que é sem os parenteses.
Porém, isso é meio ruim, pois você não vai conseguir usar os selectors do jquery, como por exemplo o $(this).
O normal é usar uma função anonima mesmo.

Comment: Eu discordo da parte final da sua resposta. A questão do `this` é um caso à parte. E não existe "o normal".

Comment: Mas onde eu usaria o seletor do jQuery em `$("a").on("click", meuOnClick);`?