# Como passar parâmetros em chamadas de funções por referência em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recentemente fiz a pergunta [**Porque devemos usar anonymous functions com jQuery ao invés da função diretamente?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3911/porque-devemos-usar-anonymous-functions-com-jquery-ao-inves-da-funcao-diretament) e junto com a resposta aceita veio uma segunda pergunta: Como passar argumentos pra uma função JS que estamos invocando por referência?

Como seria a chamada à `$("a").on("click", retornaNada);` se esta função recebesse parâmetros simples como um número ou mais complexos como um objeto propriamente dito?

Comment: Normalmente ["Chamada por referência"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrat%C3%A9gia_de_avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o#Chamada_por_refer.C3.AAncia) tem um significado um pouco diferente do que esse que você está usando.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Foi pensando nessa situação que adicionou-se entre os parâmetros do [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) a possibilidade de passar dados arbitrários à função do *handler*. Qualquer objeto passado como parâmetro logo antes do *handler* estará disponível dentro dele por meio de `event.data`. Exemplo:

```js
function retornaNada(evento) {
    var data = evento.data;
    console.log(data.foo); // Imprime "bar"
}

$("a").on("click", { foo:"bar" }, retornaNada);
```

Vários outros métodos do jQuery aceitam esse parâmetro `data`. No caso do "on", a forma geral (segundo a documentação) é:

> .on( eventos [, seletor ] [, dados ], handler(eventObject) )

Caso isso não seja suficiente para você (ex.: você já tem uma função pronta, e quer usá-la sem modificação como *handler* do evento), então é necessário transformá-la através da operação de [*currying*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21215/215). Há várias maneiras de se fazer isso:

1. *currying* "manual":

   ```
   $("a").on("click", function(e) { retornaNada(10); });
   ```
2. [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

   ```
   $("a").on("click", jQuery.proxy(retornaNada, meuThis, 10));
   ```
3. Função que retorna função:

   ```
   function tranforma(parametro) {
       return function(evento) {
           retornaNada(parametro);
       }
   }

   $("a").on("click", transforma(10));
   ```

   ou mais genérica:

   ```
   function tranforma(fn, meuThis, parametro) {
       return function(evento) {
           fn.call(meuThis, parametro);
       }
   }

   $("a").on("click", transforma(retornaNada, meuThis, 10));
   ```

   ou **ainda mais genérica** (chegando num ponto que fica quase idêntica ao `jQuery.proxy`):

   ```
   function tranforma(fn, meuThis) {
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2, arguments.length);
       return function(evento) {
           fn.apply(meuThis, args);
       }
   }

   $("a").on("click", transforma(retornaNada, meuThis, 10));
   ```

---

#### Atualização: sobre o uso do `this`

Tanto no caso do `jQuery.proxy` quanto na minha função `transforma` (nas formas mais genéricas), um parâmetro `meuThis` é esperado. Isso porque toda invocação de função em JavaScript espera um *binding* para a palavra-chave `this`, mesmo quando a função não está sendo chamada no contexo de um objeto (i.e. ela não é um **método**). Exemplo:

```
console.log(this); // Vai imprimir o "objeto global" (no caso de um browser, "window")

function a() {
    console.log(this);
}
a(); // também imprime o objeto global

var obj = { x:a };
obj.x(); // Vai imprimir "obj"

obj.criaLinks = function() {
    $("a").on("click", jQuery.proxy(retornaNada, this, 10));
    // Como se fosse: obj.retornaNada(10)

    $("a").on("click", jQuery.proxy(retornaNada, window, 10));
    // Como se fosse: window.retornaNada(10)

    $("a").on("click", jQuery.proxy(retornaNada, { foo:"bar" }, 10));
    // Como se fosse: { foo:"bar" }.retornaNada(10)
};
obj.criaLinks();
```

Comment: Seu primeiro modo de utilizar seria com utilização de função anônima, certo? E o que seria essa variável `meuThis` e qual uso no método proxy?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Em JavaScript, toda função possui um `this`. Se você não especifica um, usa-se o objeto global (no caso de um *browser*, `window`) como `this`. No caso do `jQuery.proxy`, a especificação de um `this` é obrigatória, então você tem que passar algo para ela (mesmo que não use). Se não tem um `this` pra passar, use `window`, aí ela ficaria igual a se você não tivesse usado nenhum...

Comment: No caso de um browser? Qual seria um outro caso? E passar `this` ou `window` são equivalentes, certo?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Se você estiver rodando JavaScript no lado servidor (ex.: [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino), etc) então não tem browser, e consequentemente não tem `window`. O "objeto global" nesse caso seria outro. E quanto a passar `this` ou `window` faz diferença sim: em um caso você está usando o mesmo `this` da função que chama o `proxy`, no outro você está usando `window` e ponto. Vou atualizar a resposta com um exemplo, pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Ah, já ouvi falar de Server Side JavaScript, mas infelizmente nunca vi em uso nem exemplos na internet (confesso que também não procurei muito).

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Atualizei a resposta com uma explicação bem simplificada. Se tiver mais dúvidas sobre o objeto global ou como funciona o this, sugiro abrir uma outra pergunta :)

Comment: Excelente resposta com essa última atualização, muito obrigado mesmo pela contextualização!

Answer (score 5):

O que você pode usar aqui é o [**jQuery.proxy()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

```
$('div').on('click', $.proxy( minhaFuncao, this, 'minha variavel1', 'minha variavel2' ));

function minhaFuncao(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
}
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2UPG5/)

Assim você pode passar parametros para dentro da função, mantendo a referência à função.

Este método permite passar a função referenciada, permite mudar o escopo do `this` e permite passar mais argumentos para dentro da função.

Comment: Mas aí não é mais fácil usar anonymous function mesmo? A menos que essa função seja usada em mais de um lugar é claro.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, depende: a função anónima não dá para ser referenciada. Neste caso diria que sim. Respondi para mostrar uma alternativa. Em alguns casos este método é mais util. Neste caso, como você disse, pode ser melhor com a função anónima.

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que seria **mudar o escopo de this**?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, se você tiver uma função anónima, o jQuery parra como `this` o elemento onde ele aplica o "event handler", usando com o proxy, pode mudar o this para a `window`, ou muito prático para uma `Class`. Esta técnica é muito usada.

Comment: Nesse exemplo que você deu o `this` seria o `div` então, correto? E o que seria `Class`?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, não o div seria o `window`. Class é uma classe de javascript, um objecto `{}`

Comment: Mas na sua resposta você disse que *o jQuery passa como this o elemento onde ele aplica o "event handler"* e você está aplicando o evento em um div, certo? Entendi o que é class, não sabia que objetos podiam ser chamados de class também em JS.

Answer (score 4):

Não há passagem por referência em JavaScript, mas você pode encapsular isso em um objeto (que é sempre passado por referência, já que apenas o ponteiro do objeto é passado na realidade).

Ex.:

```
function teste(argumento)
{
    argumento.valor = 10;
}

var o = { valor = 11 };

teste(o);
o.valor == 10; // true
```

Como existe apenas um único objeto na memória, as alterações deste são globais.

Comment: Mas e como eu chamaria essa sua função `teste(argumento)` dentro de um método on? `$("a").on("click", teste)`, mas onde entra seu parâmetro aqui?

Answer (score 2):

A sua pergunta anterior responde essa:

```
$("a").on("click", function() { retornaNada(param); });
```

> Tenho uma dúvida, alguns métodos do jQuery esperam uma função como
>   parâmetro, mas para funcionar devem receber uma inner function como
>   parâmetro ao invés de uma função diretamente, como no exemplo abaixo:
>
> $("a").on("click", function() { retornaNada(); }); ao invés de
>
> $("a").on("click", retornaNada());

Comment: Mas a minha dúvida agora é como passar parâmetros em uma função que chamamos por referência, ou seja, sem usar uma função anônima. E no seu exemplo você não passa parâmetros na função `retornaNada()`.

Comment: O código colado aqui é a tua pergunta anterior. Na minha opinião a melhor prática é justamente usar a chamada com o método anônimo.

Comment: Chamar com método anônimo é o jeito mais difundido, mas você sabe como seria sem o método anônimo?

Comment: Você marcou a resposta satisfatória para o seu caso. Aquela opção funciona para alguns métodos de jQuery apenas, não para javascript. Eu não vejo dificuldade em chamar com um método anônimo, na minha resposta comentei que a tua pergunta anterior, que perguntava porque se utilizava uma opção em vez de outra, a resposta mais coerente seria essa sua pergunta de agora: Utilizamos chamadas de funções anônimas para outra, justamente para passar parâmetros. 

Desculpe não ter sido claro na resposta.

Comment: Ah sim, agora entendi o que você quis dizer, eu talvez que não tenha sido claro na minha pergunta aqui. Eu nessa pergunta queria saber como passar parâmetros sem utilizar função anônima, apenas para conhecer mais a sintaxe mesmo, de qualquer maneira sua resposta agrega e votei nela também.

Comment: Perfeito. Achei bacana você ter vinculado as duas perguntas, pois elas se complementam...

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você quer passar parametros para a função `retornaNada` enquando passa ela como parametro da função on da jQuery...

Pelo que sei não há uma forma de fazer isso dentro de boas praticas, mas você poderia criar uma função que receba outra como parametro e retorne uma nova função com a chamada real dentro do escopo.

Algo assim:

```
Function.prototype.getFunction = function (context) {
    var
        args = arguments,
        foo = this;
    return function () {
        foo.apply((context || window), Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
    };
};
```

Então sua chamada ficaria assim:

```
$("a").on("click", retornaNada.getFunction(this, arg1, arg2));
```

Comment: É um jeito de fazer, mas bem mais complexo que os apresentados pelas demais respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Da forma que você está fazendo, que é utilizando um [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures%5D)(como eu lhe disse na pergunta anterior) você está passando uma referência de uma função para o argumento, que é o esperado.

Porém, Você pode utilizar parâmetros, se você retornar uma função no `return` da função que você chamou.

**Por exemplo:**

```js
function retornaFunction(data){
  return function(){console.log("Data: "+data+" This: "+this)};
}
var data = 1;
$('div').on("click", retornaFunction(data));
```

Veja que você está passando o parâmetro `data` e também pode acessar o contexto `this` que refere ao seu elemento que você clicou, do qual é muito utilizado em atribuições de funções como esta que você está propondo.

**De fato, há outras formas de fazer o que queres, não utilizando a função `.on()`.**

**Como por exemplo:**

```js
function retornaFunction(data){
      return function(){console.log("Data: "+data+" This: "+this)};
    }
    var data = 1;
$('div').click(retornaFunction(data));
```

Desta forma você não precisa passar "click" como parâmetro.

**Você, tambem pode criar um elemento e atribuir um evento de `Click` para ele em sua criação como por exemplo:**

```js
function retornaFunction(data){
  return function(){console.log("Foo: "+data+this)};
}
data = 1;
var $div = $('<div />', {
  "class": "suaclasse", //opcional apenas exemplo
  text: "texto qualquer"//opcional apenas exemplo
}).click(retornaFunction(data)); //aqui você atribui o clique.

$('body').append($div);//joga a div no body de seu documento
```

Comment: Na verdade pelo que li da documentação ao usar os métodos `click`, `change` e etc. você usa `on` implicitamente.

Comment: Tecnicamente sim, porém eu estou acostumado a usar `.click`, `.change` etc. A diferença de performance deve ser quase não existente, e é mais prático.

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se passar varios parametros via javascript usando este exemplo:

```js
function abreJanela(URL,URL2) {
location.href = "#?pg=pecas&nome="+URL+"&ano_base="+URL2;  
  
  
  //este metoo manda parametros via GET
  alert("#?pg=pecas&nome="+URL+"&ano_base="+URL2+"");
};
```

```html
<select    name="ano"  id="ano"   class="select" > 
       <option     value="2014">2014</option>
       <option     value="2015" selected>2015</option>
       </select>
Nome:<input   onchange="javascript: abreJanela(this.value, ano.value)"   type="text"  name="corrida"   >

<br>

Basta completar campo e clicar ENTER
```

Answer (score -1):

```
elementoid.on("input", $.proxy(func_atualizadigitando, this, elementoid) );

function func_atualizadigitando(tag){
    var conteudo = tag.val();
    var qtdpalavras = conteudo.split(/\S+/).length-1;
    $("#cont-palavras").text(qtdpalavras);

    var qtdcarac = conteudo.length;
    $("#cont-carac").text(qtdcarac);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione uma explicação sobre as partes relevantes do código para que seja possível entender como isso resolve a questão.