# Como determinar qual elemento HTML e/ou qual evento chamou uma função?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função chamada por dois elementos HTML diferentes e cada um dos elementos chama a função através de um determinado evento.

```
$("#tempoInicial").on("blur", manipulaTempoFinal);
$("#operadorTempo").on("change", manipulaTempoFinal);

function manipulaTempoFinal() {
    var tempoInicial = $("#tempoInicial");
    var operador = $("#operadorTempo");
    if (operador.val() == "4" && tempoInicial.val() != "") {
        tempoFinal.removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#tempoInicial, #operadorTempo").rules("remove", "skip_or_fill_minimum");
        $("#tempoInicial, #operadorTempo, #tempoFinal").rules("add", {
            require_from_group: [3, ".temposOperadorWeb"],
            messages: {
                require_from_group: "Ao entrar com tempo inicial e escolher o operador \"Entre\" o campo tempo final passa a ser obrigat&oacute;rio."
            }
        });
    } else {
        tempoFinal.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        tempoFinal.val("");
        $("#tempoInicial, #operadorTempo, #tempoFinal").rules("remove", "require_from_group");
        $("#tempoInicial, #operadorTempo").rules("add", {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".temposOperadorWeb"],
            messages: {
                skip_or_fill_minimum: "Ao preencher o tempo inicial selecione o operador ou vice-versa."
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Existe algum jeito de na função manipulaTempoFinal eu identificar quem chamou-a e/ou qual evento?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Os *listeners* de evento do jQuery recebem um parâmetro com a referência para um objeto que representa o evento. Esse objeto possui os atributos `type` e [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/), os quais contém o tipo do evento e o elemento que originalmente recebeu a ação, respectivamente.

Além disso, dentro da função, o objeto representado por `this` faz referência ao elemento que está tratando o evento, não sendo necessariamente o mesmo onde ocorreu o evento, mas pode ser um dos seus descendentes.

Exemplo:

```js
function manipulador(e) {
    console.log('evento: ' + e.type);
    console.log('componente: ' + e.target);
}

$('input, select')
    .on('change', manipulador)
    .on('blur', manipulador);
```

#### [Demo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/w7rfs/)

Entretanto, veja este outro exemplo:

```html
<div>
<input/>
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
<div>
```

```js
function manipulador(e) {
    console.log('evento: ' + e.type);
    console.log('componente: ' + e.target);
    console.log('componente: ' + this)
}

$('div')
    .on('change', manipulador)
    .on('blur', manipulador);
```

Neste último exemplo, o resultado no console para um evento `change` seria:

> evento: change
>
> componente: [object HTMLInputElement]
>
> componente: [object HTMLDivElement]

Note que `target` retornou o `input` que **recebeu** o evento, enquanto `this` retornou o `div` que **tratou** o evento.

#### [Demo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/pdr6J/)

Comment: Excelente resposta! Agregou bastante saber essa informação. Só uma pergunta, do jeito que você fez você agrega tanto ao change quando ao blur dos selects e inputs a função, correto?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Correto!

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Note que atualizei a reposta com algumas nuances sobre `event.target` e `this`.

Comment: Melhorou ainda mais mesmo a resposta, ou seja, utilizar o this nem sempre poderia resolver meu problema dependendo de como foi chamado. Obrigado mesmo pelo conhecimento!

Comment: +1, muito mais claro. =)

Answer (score 5):

A palavra-chave `this` vai sempre possuir a referência ao elemento que disparou o evento.

Assim, se dentro da sua função você chamar `$(this)` Você obterá a referência com um envelope jQuery.

[**Tem um post bom no SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552110/using-the-context-of-the-this-keyword-with-jquery) a respeito disso. Texto original:

> In jQuery, by default, `this` refers to the DOM element (not a jQuery
>   object) which triggered an event. In the [code snippet above], it
>   is still the same DOM element, only it is wrapped in a jQuery element
>   by wrapping `$()` around it. As with any argument to the jQuery
>   constructor, passing this into the constructor transforms it into a
>   jQuery object.

Traduzindo:

> Em jQuery, por padrão, a palavra-chave `this` refere-se ao elemento DOM (não um objeto jQuery) que desencadeou um evento. No [trecho de código acima], ainda é o mesmo elemento DOM, só que é envolto em um elemento jQuery por possuir `$()` em torno dele. Como acontece com qualquer argumento para um construtor jQuery, passando este para o construtor transforma-o em um objeto jQuery.

Caso você queria saber qual evento foi disparado, você pode fazer de maneira indireta, passando um alias na chamada do evento. Exemplo:

```
$("#tempoInicial").on("blur", function(e) { manipulaTempoFinal('blur'); });
```

E a assinatura da sua função pode ficar assim:

```
function manipulaTempoFinal(pEvento)
[...]
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava. Só complementando, você saberia dizer o evento?

Comment: Não diretamente, mas você pode passar um alias da operação na chamada da função. Eu vou editar a resposta pra adicionar essa parte. [Edit] Tá lá, @PhilippeGioseffi. Espero que funcione pra você!

Comment: Só um adendo, acho que não se consegue passar parâmetros para funções do jeito que você fez, olhe a pergunta: [Como passar parâmetros em chamadas de funções por referência em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3924/como-passar-parametros-em-chamadas-de-funcoes-por-referencia-em-javascript).

Comment: Correto. Atualizado. Preciso de café. =)

Comment: De qualquer maneira, obrigado pela ajuda!