# Passar função para outra função como parâmetro com parametro nessa função em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

O titulo pode parecer meio confuso mas o que eu quero é basicamente isso:
no onclick do botão passar para uma função A uma função B como parametro. Só que já passar um parametro sobre o qual B irá operar que no caso é excluir o produto.

Tenho uma lista de produtos cada um com um código diferente.
Tenho o seguinte botão para cada produto que no onclick tem a função modalConfirmacao() onde passo como parâmetro o titulo e mensagem do modal e a função a ser executada que no caso é excluirProduto():

```
<a onClick="script: modalConfirmacao('+"'Confirmar'"+','+"'Tem certeza que deseja excluir?'"+',excluirProduto('+produtos.codigo+'));"> <i class=" fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Excluir</a>
```

O problema é que sem eu confirmar a exclusão ele já ta chamando a função excluirProduto(). Na última linha do trecho de código abaixo vocês percebem que só deve ser chamada a função passada via parametro se for clicado no botão ok. Mas antes disso ele ja executa a funcao.

```
function modalConfirmacao(titulo, mensagem,funcao) {
    var htmlModal = '<div class="modal fade" id="modalConfirmacao" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">' +
                        '<div class="modal-dialog">'+
                            '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                '<!-- Modal Header -->'+
                                '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                    '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'+
                                        titulo
                                    +'</h4>'+
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">'+
                                        '&times;'+
                                    '</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<!-- Modal Body -->'+
                                '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                    mensagem
                                +'</div>'+
                                '<!-- Modal Footer -->'+
                                '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                    '<button type="button" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">'+
                                        'OK'+
                                    '</button>'+
                                    '<button type="button" id="cancelar" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">'+
                                        'Cancelar'+
                                    '</button>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
            $('body').append(htmlModal);
            $("#modalConfirmacao").modal();
            $("#ok").off("click").on("click",funcao);
}
```

Creio que seja por causa dos parenteses mas preciso usar eles para passar o parametro produto.codigo que é o produto a ser excluido.

Então como eu posso passar a  função excluirProduto() juntamente com o parametro sem executá-la?

Comment: De onde vem `produtos.codigo`... vc está inserindo uma variável JS em um elemento HTML.

Comment: Isso está dentro de um each do javascript, eu estou iterando em array de produtos para coloca-los em uma lista. Isso tudo no javascript

Comment: Conseguiu? Postou a resposta e apagou!

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver meu problema baseado na resposta dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3924/como-passar-par%C3%A2metros-em-chamadas-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-por-refer%C3%AAncia-em-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1) :

No meu caso no meu link tinha isso:

```
<a onClick="script: modalConfirmacao('+"'Confirmar'"+','+"'Tem certeza que deseja excluir?'"+',excluirProduto('+produtos.codigo+'));"> <i class=" fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Excluir</a>
```

E mudei para isso:

```
<a onClick="script: modalConfirmacao('+"'Confirmar'"+','+"'Tem certeza que deseja excluir?'"+', jQuery.proxy(excluirProduto,this,'+produto.codigo+')));"> <i class=" fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Excluir</a>
```

Funcionando que é uma beleza.